# Get last year date from entered date in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to get same date with last year.

Here is my query:

```
select 
    convert(datetime, (select DATEADD(year, -1, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, '01/04/2016'), 0))), 103)
```

I am getting date like this `2015-01-04 00:00:00.000`

I want it with same format as I entered in query.

Does anyone have any idea for it?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query uses product specific functionality.) When it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: Fix the format you provide in the query:  `'2016-04-01'`.  All constants should really be using ISO/ANSI standard date formats.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using SQLServer

you can use `FORMAT` function to get `dd/MM/yyyy` dateformat

```
SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(year,-1, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0,'01/04/2016'), 0)),'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/154a3/1*

Comment: My fail,I forgot to ask you Which SQLServer version did you use?
`FORMAT` function support version higher than 2012

Answer (score 0):

When using `CONVERT` in MSSQL, the date formatter 103 which represents *dd/MM/yyyy* is used to either convert a `DATE` (or `DATETIME`)  value to a CHAR value with that format; or convert from  CHAR value with that format to a `DATE` (or `DATETIME`). I believe what you are looking for is:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(YEAR,-1,CONVERT(DATE,'01/04/2016',103)),103);
```

The innermost expression, `CONVERT(DATE,'01/04/2016',103)` converts the `CHAR` value '01/04/2016' to `DATE` then 1 year is substracted to this value and then converted back to `CHAR` with the `dd/MM/yyyy` (103) format.

Comment: yes i got this, not in date datatype. but its use full for me. thank you sir